# Let $G$ a group, prove that $o(ab)\mid [o(a),o(b)]$.

Tags: group-theory

let $G$ a group, prove that $o(ab)\mid [o(a),o(b)]$.It is trivially easy if $G$ is abelian; I can't prove it in general.

Thanks.

Comment: $o(x)$ meaning order of $x$? If so, do you mean $o(ab) \mid o([a, b])$?

Comment: It's not true in general. The product of two transpositions can be a $3$-cycle, for example.

Comment: This was the reason of my failure.

Comment: Could someone tell me what the question means, please?

Comment: Yes excuse me: $o(x)$ was the order of $x$. So I ask a way to demonstrate the (false) property of the order of product: $o(a)\mid lcm(o(a),o(b))$. It is clear now?

Comment: It can be event more extreme than in Daniel Fischer's example: in the free product of two copies of a 2-element group, the order of $ab$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the generators of the factors) is infinite, while the lcm of their orders is 2.

Comment: @G.Cantisani: thank you: the notation $[m, n]$ for an lcm is not well-known (at least to me $\ddot{\smile}$!). I genuinely thought you were interested in the order of the commutator $[a, b]$.

Comment: Every $A_n$ is generated by elements of order $3$. Iteration of your claim would yield that every element of $A_n$ satisfies $x^3=e$, which is not true for $n\ge 5$, because $5\mid\#A_n=\frac{n!}{2}$.